# C# fetch all text from git log command

Tags: c#, git, process.start

I am trying to obtain all the text from the `git log` command via C# Process.Start.

I need the full output for a tool that i am working on.

The problem I am facing is that UseShellExecute = false ommits some info from the result:

```
commit 77832ec07a2f96c2151c7a2f6ed0417e7e836eca (HEAD -> master)
Author: xxx yyy <xxx.yyy @zzz.com>
Date:   Thu Jul 21 12:28:26 2022 +0300

    wip

commit f2cac40abf3d4b0cb2109376a635f9b8bd2ae56a
Author: xxx yyy <xxx.yyy @zzz.com>
Date:   Tue Jun 21 16:33:57 2022 +0300

    wip
```

so from this output the (HEAD -> master) part gets ommited if i use UseShellExecute = false and if i use UseShellExecute = true i can't capture the output of the process.

I know it has to do something with the fact that those parts of the output get colored so i also tried running `git log --no-color` but for no avail.

Method declaration:

```
    private string ExecProcessWait(string path, string arguments, string workingDir)
    {
        var proc = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = path,
                Arguments = arguments,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                WorkingDirectory = workingDir
            },
            EnableRaisingEvents = true,
        };

        var output = string.Empty;

        proc.ErrorDataReceived += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Data != null)
            {
                output += e.Data;
            }
        };

        proc.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (e.Data != null)
            {
                output += $"{e.Data}{Environment.NewLine}";
            }
        };


        proc.Start();
        proc.BeginErrorReadLine();
        proc.BeginOutputReadLine();

        proc.WaitForExit();

        proc.Dispose();

        return output;
    }
```

Code sample:

```
var output = ExecProcessWait("git.exe", "log", @"Git_repo_dir");
```

[@selvin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/690952/selvin) suggested to try a C# git library so i followed [this](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/wiki/git-log#libgit2sharp) example (LibGit2Sharp) but sadly the same information is missing from it as well.

Comment: Why didn't you use some git library for this? I'm pretty sure that there is one for c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git log` is what Git calls a *porcelain* command, as opposed to what Git calls a *plumbing* command.  Plumbing commands are meant to be used by other programs and therefore behave well when used by other programs: their output format is well-defined and they don't depend on user configurations or other settings.  Porcelain commands are the opposite: their output is squishy and changes without warning, depends on user configurations, and generally cannot be relied-on.

Unfortunately, `git log` has no exact plumbing equivalent.  This means that if you need one of the things that *only* `git log` can provide—and can't use something other than a Git command in the first place, e.g., can't use libgit2sharp for some reason—you're stuck with invoking `git log`.  You'll just have to use it very carefully.  First, though, you should exhaust other alternatives.

Now, as to this:

> I know it has to do something with the fact that those parts of the output get colored

It's *related*, but not the same thing.

> so I also tried running `git log --no-color` but for no avail.

You'll generally want `--no-color` and `--no-pager` to avoid depending on the user's color and pager preferences.

> ... the (HEAD -> master) part gets omitted

This part is what `git log` calls a *decoration*.  Its presence or absence is controlled by the `--decorate` or `--no-decorate` option.  If neither option is specified, it defaults to `--decorate=auto` (since Git 2.1 but accidentally undocumented until Git 2.9).  The `auto` setting means *on if a human appears to be reading the output, but off if a program appears to be reading the output*.  The user can configure, via global or local `git config` settings, `log.decorate` to `short` or `full` or `no`, which will change this from the default "detect whether a program is reading the output" mode.

This sort of thing is *why* using porcelain commands from other commands is generally a bad idea: there are too many things that can go wrong.

Note that if you want to find all refs that point to a particular commit hash ID, `git for-each-ref` is the plumbing command that does that (and only that).  Of course, if you also want to see the commit *message*, you need `git log`.  You'll need to carefully control the format (`--format=...` or `--pretty=tformat:...` for instance), as well as all those user settings (`--decorate=`, `--no-pager`, `--no-color`, and so on).  The `git log` really needs a `--porcelain` option the way `git status` has one now.  (`--porcelain` means *yes, this is normally a porcelain command, turn it into a plumbing one for me* and logically this should be `--no-porcelain` or `--plumbing`.  Nobody ever said Git was consistent or logical.)